# Connecting to Wifi in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, wifi, ssid

I'v been poking around the internet for the past hour and a half trying to find a windows command similar to `wifi connect ssid="YOURSSID" passcode="YOURPASSCODE"`, and I cant seem to find it! I found wlan, but that has something to do with profiles, and stuff. I don't want to create any profiles, or refrence them! I just want to run the command on its own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started...

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=SSID1
```

UPDATE: Apparently this requires a profile.

Answer (score 0):

You need a xml file that has the SSID and password.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>{example}</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>{6578616d706c65}</hex>
            <name>{example}</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization 
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Fill in the `{6578616d706c65}`, `{example}`, `{example}` and `{password}` with your own information.
`{6578616d706c65}` is the Hex of `example`, click [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.htm) to convert ASCII to HEX.

Make sure you use the correct format, windows WILL NOT accept even there's one more space at the end.

click [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y6d0RtIRbs4x6HiJI1891dfgtC3vyyLw) to download `example.xml` and other files.

If you want to use pure cmd to connect (without changing the `{password}` manually), keep reading

To do this, you will need 36 xml files with a-z and 0-9.

click [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y6d0RtIRbs4x6HiJI1891dfgtC3vyyLw) to download the 36 files and example.xml.

First you need to separate example.xml into 3 parts, the first part is from `<?xml version="1.0"?>` to `<keyMaterial>`.
Name that to `T.xml`.

The second part is the password.

The third part is from `</keyMaterial>` to the end (`</WLANProfile>`) make sure you don't forget the line break after `</WLANProfile>`.
Name that to `B.xml`.

Then you will use the copy command to combine the files.

The code should look like this

```
copy /y C:\T.xml + C:\keyMaterial\p.xml + C:\keyMaterial\a.xml + C:\keyMaterial\s.xml + C:\keyMaterial\s.xml + C:\keyMaterial\w.xml + C:\keyMaterial\o.xml + C:\keyMaterial\r.xml + C:\keyMaterial\d.xml + C:\B.xml C:\example.xml /B
netsh wlan add profile filename="C:\example.xml" user=all
netsh wlan connect example
```

Finally, you can check if you're connected by running `ping google.com`.